# How to find all paths in a NxM grid?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is my problem:

> A robot is located at the top-left corner of a m x n grid
>
> The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid.
>
> How many possible unique paths are there?

This is my code:

```
def paths(m,n,a,b,memo):

    if(a == 0 or b == 0):
        return 0

    if m>a or n>b:
        return 0

    if m==a and n==b:
        return 1
   
    if str(m)+str(n) in memo:
        return memo[str(m)+str(n)]
    else:  
        memo[str(m)+str(n)] = paths(m+1,n,a,b,memo) + paths(m,n+1,a,b,memo)
        return memo[str(m)+str(n)] 

m=23
n=12
memo =  dict()
print(paths(0,0,m-1,n-1,memo))
```

I am getting correct answer for most of the cases, but for case where m=23 and n=12, my answer is wrong. Correct answer is `193536720` while I am getting `201648450`

Comment: Wouldn't `str(21)+str(2)` equal `str(2)+str(12)` and therefore you'd get the wrong values?

Comment: ohh, such a silly mistake. Thanks, I changed  `str(m)+str(n)`  to `str(m)+" "+str(n) ` and it worked.

Comment: I suspect these string conversions are going to slow down your code quite a lot. Why not just store `(m,n)` tuples in the cache instead of converting these values to strings — i.e., `memo[(m,n)] = paths(m+1,n,a,b,memo) + paths(m,n+1,a,b,memo)` and `if (m,n) in memo: return memo[(m,n)]`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - Thanks, you were right. Running time improved a lot. :)

Comment: This is just a simple Math problem, there is a formula for this problem

Comment: Pham Trung is right. It is m+n-2 choose m-1 or m+n-2 choose n-1 which is the same. Written with factorials: (m+n-2)!/(m-1)!/(n-1)!